# Why can't GCHandle.Alloc pin objects containing references?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, pinvoke

I suspect that the reason this function doesn't exist is that implementing it is complex and that few people need it.  To be safe, you'd want pinning to work transitively, i.e., you'd want the entire graph of reachable objects to be pinned.  But it doesn't seem like something that fundamentally can't be done.

E.g., suppose you have the following class:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
class SomeObject
{
    public SomeObject r;
}
```

which you allocate like:

```
SomeObject o = new SomeObject();
```

and you try to pin it with:

```
GCHandle oh = GCHandle.Alloc(o, GCHandleType.Pinned);
```

you'll get the dreaded:

```
Object contains non-primitive or non-blittable data.
```

OK, fine, I can live with that.  But suppose I had access to .NET's garbage collector implementation.  What would be the obstacles?  Here are the obstacles I see:

1. Circular references.
2. You want the garbage collector to limit itself to objects inside the app's heap(s).
3. It could take a long time.
4. It would be hard/painful to make the operation atomic.

It seems to me that the GC already has to deal with some of these issues.  So what am I forgetting?

NOTE: Before you ask "What are you trying to accomplish?", etc., the purpose of my asking is for research code, not necessarily limited to C#, and not necessarily limited to the CLR.  I understand that fiddling with the runtime's own memory is not a typical scenario.  In any case, this isn't a purely speculative question.

NOTE 2: Also, I don't care about marshaling.  I'm just concerned about pinning.

Answer (score 10):

The GC just knows that whatever you are going to next isn't going to work.  You pin memory for a *reason*, surely it is to obtain a stable IntPtr to the object.   Which you then next, say, pass to unmanaged code.

There is however a problem with the *content* of the pointed-to memory.  It contains a pointer to a managed object.  That pointer is going to **randomly** change whenever another thread allocates memory and triggers a collection.  Which will play havoc on any code that uses the pinned memory content.  There is no way to obtain a stable pointer, you can't "freeze" the collector.  Pinning the pointer doesn't work either, it just passes the buck to the next pointed-to object.  GCHandle.Alloc doesn't travel the entire dependency graph to check that, there's no decent upper-bound on how long that can take.  Circular references, perfectly legal in managed code, are very expensive to detect.  Getting an entire generation pinned is technically possible, that's a very hard deadlock.

Ugly problems, it was just much simpler to forbid it.  Not much of a real problem, pinvoke happens everyday anyway.

Comment: What would it mean if you modified a reference inside a pinned object? Would it unpin the old reference and pin the new one? Calculating the transitive closure of the references is about as expensive as a GC. Now you want to do this any time any reference changes anywhere in the system?

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense.  For starters, nothing about the GC is random.  Out of your control, yes.  But this is beside the point: if I pin an object, I have a stable pointer to that object.  Now, I find the fields of that pinned object (also stable), get a reference to the pointed-to object and pin it.  Nothing in this process makes references less stable, and so, by induction, I should be able to pin the entire object graph transitively.  You'd want to avoid pinning more than once, but that is an implementation detail.  I WANT to pin the whole object graph, which is why I ask.

Comment: Hmya, I didn't expect you to be pleased with the answer.  You say you'll get it right, the CLR designers doubted it, said "no" and that's the end of it.  You can post feature requests to connect.microsoft.com or have it your way with Mono.

Comment: @Hans Passant you can design your class so that fields in the beginning is compatable with pinvoked function, and add extra reference types for your own use. you say CLR is not sure if you are able to take right steps to make things work and prevent it. i can break it with 1 line of simple code if i wanted to?